# Append Numpy ndarray to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have ten numpy ndarrys each having one row and 100 columns. Now I want to append them sequentially to a pandas dataframe (should have 10 rows and 100 columns in the end). How can I achieve that in python:

```
# create empty dataframe
data = pd.DataFrame()

# Loop
for i in range(1, 11):

    # Simulate ndarrys
    one_row = np.array([range(1, 101)])

    # Trying to append
    data = data.append(data, one_row)
```

Comment: Stack with `np.vstack` and at the end use `pd.Dataframe()`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create iteratively the array, to make it 10x100, then pass it to `DataFrame`.

You can use `np.insert` or `np.vstack` to create the 10x100 array.

Comment: Some code to explain how to achieve it would be helpful